# don't work checkbox "remember me" in "Log in" form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Good day for everyone.
I'm working at the Chapter 8 "Log in, log out" of Rails Tutorial (3ed)

And in Listing 8.58 i have an Erro in integration tests.

```
FAIL["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil"
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", 
created_at:      "2014-11-25 08:52:36", updated_at: "2014-11-25 08:52:36",       
password_digest: "$2a$04$PqPt.GZHyu3xKlQWh4UJM./y7pEz2w9Twp2XOlg0Eor...",
remember_digest: "$2a$04$hDNgctx0rqYZq9sH4ZO3Lu1MfkfGKtXgdN11Lhv.yVD...">
+nil
test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

In this part of session_helper.rb

```
test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
assert_equal @user, current_user #in this line i have an error
assert is_logged_in?
end
```

my session_controller.rb

```
  def create
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  log_in user
  params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
  redirect_to user
else
  flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
  render 'new'
end
end
```

my session_helper.rb

```
      # Forgets a persistent session.
def forget(user)
user.forget
cookies.delete(:user_id)
cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

and my form with checkbox

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox inline" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
</div>
</div>
```

i'm tried all my minds.. Thank you

And i think, i have a wrong work this checkbox, if it unmarked, my session still work, and user-session exit only if I press log out link.

Comment: once try with `assert_equal user, current_user #in this line i have an error`

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `user'

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorial (I'm at the end of Ch9).

I see that you gave a snipped of what you said is part of `session_helper.rb` but my matching code for test `"current_user returns right user when session is nil"` is located in `test\helpers\sessions_helper_test.rb`.

Do you mind posting the full contents of that file?  Here's a snippet of the first 8 lines of that file (everything minus the actual tests).  I am inclined to believe you forgot to add the setup method:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:xxx) # Where xxx is the name of the user in users.yml
    remember(@user)
  end
.
.
.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@current_user` in place of `current_user`. `current_user` is a local variable which is not found in the test scope, while `@current_user` is an instance variable which is accessible globally. Hope that helps.